# pass variable from a component to TitleWindow in Flex4

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, popup, flex4.5

I am trying to access a variable defined in an mxml component from a `TitleWindow` but I cannot get it. I also declared a variable in my `titleWindow` which references to the component. And I also tried using `parentDocument` to access the variable but in vain.

Any precious help on this. Thanks.

See my codes below:

```
This is my component (Comp.xml) where I have declared the variable testVar.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
         width="100%" height="100%">


    <fx:Script>

        <![CDATA[
public var testVar:String = "Testing";

    ]]>
    </fx:Script>

</s:Group>

This is my titleWindow code:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:TitleWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" left="10" 
               creationComplete="titlewindow1_initializeHandler(event)"
               width="100%" height="100%"
>



    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.controls.Alert;
import com.Comp;

public var varComp:Comp;

            public function titlewindow1_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {

                //Alert.show(new String(Application));
                Alert.show(new String(varComp.testVar));
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:TitleWindow>
```